RecyclerView is not priting all the data when the database file works normally
I'm making a simple task manager app for my study but there's a problem with my recycle view that is not showing all my data. I added 3 different table and it's only showing the first one on my recyclerview. Was hoping if you guys can help check out what seems to be the problem. I thank you very much for helping
This is my database which works fine
1   Testing 123 Testing to see if work  17/5/2024
2   Testing 456 Testing 2nd time    17/5/2024
3   Tsting again    Testing checking the database   31/5/2024
MainActivity.java
package com.example.a41p;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;


import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton add_button;
    MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String> task_title, task_description, task_duedate;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize views
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        add_button = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> {
            // Navigate back to MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish(); // Finish current activity
        });

        // Set onClickListener for the FloatingActionButton
        add_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
            addActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        });

        myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        task_title = new ArrayList<>();
        task_description = new ArrayList<>();
        task_duedate = new ArrayList<>();

        // Store data from the database into the array
        storeDataInArrays(false);

        // Set up the RecyclerView with the CustomAdapter
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, this, task_title, task_description, task_duedate);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    }


    //I think is the problem but seems to look fine
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> addActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Append new data to the RecyclerView
                    storeDataInArrays(true);
                    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
    );

    void storeDataInArrays(boolean append) {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (!append) {
                task_title.clear();
                task_description.clear();
                task_duedate.clear();
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                task_title.add(cursor.getString(1));
                task_description.add(cursor.getString(2));
                task_duedate.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }
        }
    }
}

my activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="Task List"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/floatingActionButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="96dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

This is what it looks like
I think this part is the problem since i did ask chatgpt about it but it said that this looks fine, my goal is just to print out the cardview each time i added a new task.
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> addActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Append new data to the RecyclerView
                    storeDataInArrays(true);
                    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
    );

This is my CustomApdapter which works with the my_row xml
package com.example.a41p;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final Activity activity;
    private final ArrayList<String> task_title;
    private final ArrayList<String> task_description;
    private final ArrayList<String> task_duedate;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList<String> task_title, ArrayList<String> task_description, ArrayList<String> task_duedate) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.task_title = task_title;
        this.task_description = task_description;
        this.task_duedate = task_duedate;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.task_title_txt.setText(task_title.get(position));
        holder.task_description_txt.setText(task_description.get(position));
        holder.task_duedate_txt.setText(task_duedate.get(position));

        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", String.valueOf(task_title.get(adapterPosition)));
                intent.putExtra("description", String.valueOf(task_description.get(adapterPosition)));
                intent.putExtra("due date", String.valueOf(task_duedate.get(adapterPosition)));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return task_title.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView task_title_txt, task_description_txt, task_duedate_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            task_title_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title_txt);
            task_description_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_description_txt);
            task_duedate_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_duedate_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        }
    }

}

my_row.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="172dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="171dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/task_title_txt"
                android:layout_width="354dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/task_description_txt"
                android:layout_width="356dp"
                android:layout_height="67dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_title_txt"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/task_duedate_txt"
                android:layout_width="141dp"
                android:layout_height="29dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Due Date"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_description_txt"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>


Ps. Answering the first comment: This is the database, it's only showing the first one, not the other 2. Database open in SQLite

can u share an image of your database? from app inspection or any other way to verify that you have more than 1 data in there?

Yeah, i add the image at the bottom of the question. It's only showing the first one, not the other 2.

maybe try to refresh directly below the data add part
and change the height of your my_row xml parent layout to warp content if u dont want it to take hole screen (if u want to leave it)
you can even get the proper position of your list then use   customAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
void storeDataInArrays(boolean append) {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (!append) {
            task_title.clear();
            task_description.clear();
            task_duedate.clear();
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            task_title.add(cursor.getString(1));
            task_description.add(cursor.getString(2));
            task_duedate.add(cursor.getString(3));
        }
         customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


Oh my god, thank you so much. Mad mistake by using match_parent instead of match_content. Silly me

plz upvote people who help you
